# As I make irssi, not being able to login as root - how can irssi be run?

Tags: unix, terminal, makefile, archlinux

The problem is without having sudo or root permissions, while I am still able to use the commands: make and ./configure. I am unable to run make install but would like to find the binary executable. Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the installation path to somewhere you have write access to. Try the following:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME
make
make install
```

That should install it to ~/bin/

Comment: If you don't mind, please mark the answer as 'correct' then :-)

Comment: Done, sorry had to wait 9 minutes until it would let me :-)